# Maven downloads snapshots from from release URL when connected to VPN

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vpn

I have a strange issue where when i connect to my work VPN and i update my maven module from Terminal or Eclipse, Maven tries to download from the wrong URL (releases) however when I'm at work, it connect to the correct URL.

My settings.xml looks find i have checked it multiple times.

If anyone could point me to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I realized recently that the DNS server of my company is used rather than the one of my provider at home when connected via VPN. Maybe your company's DNS behaves differently when connected via VPN vs. connected internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to comment out the proxy setting in my settings.xml which are needed when in the office but not when im at home using VPN.